# Spring Boot - Application losing DB connection in PRD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I read a lot of questions here in stackoverflow about this subject and I ended with the following code in my application-prd.properties:

```
#PRD IP
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

# Fix for DB Connection
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=10
spring.datasource.tomcat.initial-size=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=5
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=1
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.tomcat.validation-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.tomcat.time-between-eviction-runs-millis=5000
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-evictable-idle-time-millis=60000

#Error fix for JSON conversion
spring.jackson.parser.allow-unquoted-control-chars=true
```

But, for some reason, the Tomcat with my Spring application suddenly loses the connection with the database, giving the following error:

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

I don't know what should I do. Its been weeks that I'm struggling with it. Is there anything else that I can do? Or can I say that is a firewall issue and the infrastructure team should check something?

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to connect database with any database client tool? Like datastudio or mysql client. Also if you have IP then try to ping url.

Comment: I am only able to connect again if I restart tomcat.

Comment: Did you try to increase connection pool size? What happen if you increase the size?

Answer (score -1):

Also check for connection leaks, might be some txns not closing connection properly that's why pool went out of threshold.